# Highcharts - data day sum one day ahead

Tags: highcharts

Good evening (CET),

I collect data, calculate a day sum, store the value in mySQL with a time stamp close to 24h of that day (like August 4, 23:59:30).

In a Highchart Column graph, the value will be shown on the August 5th. (You will see this be hovering over the bar, that the value doesn't fit to the xAxis.)

A working example is at http://jsfiddle.net/bg8yu3ft/

```
// data
var data = [ [1501624793000, 3389], [1501883993000, 4045], [1501970397000, 6572], [1502056798000, 5836], [1502143193000, 4736], [1502229588000, 6629],  [1502315996000, 3981], [1502402391000, 4424] ]

// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: data,
  }]
});
```

Looking forward to any advice to center the bar on the day it belongs to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all your data is going to be in the same format (i.e. close to midnight) you can do it easily with `pointplacement` like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/bg8yu3ft/1/). Depending on your timezone you might have to adjust the value a little.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        data: data,
        pointPlacement: -1.2
        }]
});
```

Another option would be to move the ticks, [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.tickPositions).

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `x` data to the closes full day then in the chart all will work fine and axis, point, tooltip will show `x` values as full days.

If you need to have precise day in the tooltip, then you could show it as an info. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7uhdfcj4/

```js
// data
var data = [
  [1501624793000, 3389],
  [1501883993000, 4045],
  [1501970397000, 6572],
  [1502056798000, 5836],
  [1502143193000, 4736],
  [1502229588000, 6629],
  [1502315996000, 3981],
  [1502402391000, 4424],
];

Highcharts.each(data, function(d, i) {
  var realTime = d[0],
    date = Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y:%m:%d:%H:%M:%S:%L', realTime).split(':'),
    day = (+date[2]) + ((+date[3]) > 19 ? 1 : 0);

  data[i].push(realTime);
  data[i][0] = Date.UTC(+date[0], +date[1], day);
});

// create the chart
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    data: data,
    keys: ['x', 'y', 'realTime'],
    tooltip: {
      pointFormat: '{point.realTime: %Y.%m.%d %H:%M:%S}'
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>


<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```